# How to create a DataTemplate programmatically with MAUI for Windows

Tags: .net, maui, maui-windows

I'm trying to create a data template for a collection view with .NET MAUI. So far, it's been working with Android but not on Windows.

First, I created a border that will be the data template base. Second, I created the data template from the border, added the data template to the page resource dictionary and finally set the collection view ItemTemplate to the created data template.

All the code is in the constructor of the page in a try/catch but never goes into the catch section. The binding context is also set with the last instruction.

Here is the code in MainPage.cs:

```
            AbsoluteLayout mainLayout = new AbsoluteLayout().LoadFromXaml(xaml);

            CollectionView collectionViewTest = mainLayout.FindByName<CollectionView>("CollectionViewTest");

            Border collectionViewBorderTemplate = new CollectionViewTestBorder();
            TapGestureRecognizer tapGesture = new();
            tapGesture.Tapped += TapGesture_Tapped;
            collectionViewBorderTemplate.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGesture);

            DataTemplate dataTemplate = new() {
                LoadTemplate = () => collectionViewBorderTemplate 
            };

            collectionViewTest.ItemTemplate = dataTemplate;
            
            ObservableCollection<User> users = new() {
                new User { Name = "Joe", Email = "test@mail.com", Age = 40 },
                new User { Name = "Jane", Email = "test1@mail.com", Age = 50 },
                new User { Name = "James", Email = "test2@mail.com", Age = 35 }
            };
            
            collectionViewTest.ItemsSource = users;
            BindingContext = vm;
```

Here is the code of the CollectionViewTestBorder.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Border xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DesignADistance.Components.CollectionViewTestBorder"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:DesignADistance.Models"
             x:DataType="models:User">
    <Grid RowDefinitions="100,100,100">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="PowderBlue"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Age}"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Email}"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Everything works fine when I'm running the project with the Android emulator but when running it with Windows, I get this error in a App.g.i.cs:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcNgO.png)

[Error sender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j66p3.png)

Here is the e.Exception.StackTrace message:

```
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.ItemContentControl.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IFrameworkElementOverrides.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IFrameworkElementOverrides.Do_Abi_MeasureOverride_0(IntPtr thisPtr, Size availableSize, Size* result)
```

Here is the e.Exception.Message:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

It seems like the resource dictionary is not initialized properly even though I created a new instance of it. What should I do differently on Windows to get it working?

Comment: why are you creating a `ResourceDictionary` if you are just assigning the `DataTemplate` directly?  `collectionViewTest.ItemTemplate = dataTemplate;` should work

Comment: I saw that as an exemple in the Xamarin.Forms documentation after trying what you suggest. I tried again with `collectionViewTest.ItemTemplate = dataTemplate;` without success. I removed the line `collectionViewTest.ItemsSource = users;` and the program started without an error. The error arises when I try to set the ItemsSource property with the ObservableCollection.

Comment: Get it working first with code jason suggested. Perhaps the current exception is misleading. If you wrap all that code in try..catch, do you get same exception in the catch block? And please copy/paste complete error text into the question, so don’t have to rely on link. Is that code in *constructor*? Put it after InitializeComponent, and before BindingContext is set.

Comment: I updated the code a little bit and added the source of the error. The code is indeed in the constructor and is in a try..catch block but never goes into the catch section. Everything is after InitializeComponent and the bindingContext is set with the last instruction. I unfortunately do not have more from the exception that what I posted before.

Comment: This looks like a Layout exception in windows platform on Maui. Can you provide the repro project?